# Split variable in 2 after the last dot

Tags: windows, batch, environment-variables

I need to cut variables in two smaller variables after the last dot.
For example the variable "`european.union`" will be `vara=european` and `varb=union`

I use the following code to accomplish this purpose:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ("%elvariato%") do set vara=%%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims=." %%a in ("%elvariato%") do set varb=%%a
```

The problem is that this code can't manage multiple "`.`" split variables. For example the variable `spain is in.the.european.union` would totally make this code useless.

`vara="spain is in"` `varb=the` would be the output but i need `vara="spain is in.the.european"` `varb=union`

Don't worry about in var spaces, i can manage them.

I want to split the variable at the last dot `.` but i don't know how to accomplish that. I tried to read the total number of tokens to merge all the tokens up to  N-1 but it did not work. Being unable to know the number of dots before the variable is analyzed by the script makes it kinda hard. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my suggestion is to use PowerShell ;-).

```
$text = "spain is in.the.european.union"
$vara = $text.Substring(0, $text.lastIndexOf('.'))
$varb = $text.Split(".")[-1]
```

output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $vara
spain is in.the.european

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $varb
union
```

to use this in a cmd script, this will set `%vara%` and `%varb%` correctly, to use it further in your cmd script.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' powershell "$env:elvariato.Substring(0, $env:elvariato.lastIndexOf('.'))" ') do set "vara=%%a"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' powershell "$env:elvariato.split('.')[-1]" ') do set "varb=%%a"
```

`%vara%` contains `spain is in.the.european` and `%varb%` contains `union` in this case

**Explanation:**

- `Substring(0, $text.lastIndexOf('.'))` gets everything from the beginning of the string (`0`) up until the last `.`
- `split('.')[-1]` splits your string on each dot and gets the last value in the created array

Comment: Thx, it works!!!

Comment: My company turns off powershell. I can't use powershell.

Comment: @DavidGleba my condolences. you are not the OP though I believe, so if you don't find a batch answer, you'll have to ask your own question

Answer (score 2):

The following (partially commented) code snippet shows pure batch-file solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
rem default/expected: SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if "%~1"=="" (
  set "elvariato=spain is in.the.european.union"      asked example value
) else (
  set "elvariato=%~1"                                 supplied sample value 
)
set "_dot_pos="      
set "nodots=%elvariato:.=%"                           check for any dot presence
if "%nodots%"=="%elvariato%" goto :jjloopEnd          
set /a jj=1
:jjloop              compute last dot position (counted from the end of string)
  call set "_auxiliary=%%elvariato:~-%jj%%%"
  set "_aux_1char=%_auxiliary:~0,1%"
  if "%_aux_1char%"=="." (
      set /A _dot_pos=jj
      set /A _dot_pre=jj - 1
      goto :jjloopEnd
  )
  set /a jj+=1
  goto :jjloop
:jjloopEnd
if not defined _dot_pos (
    rem string does not contain any dot character at all
    set "vara=%elvariato%"
    set "varb="
    goto :showResults
)
call set "vara=%%elvariato:~0,-%_dot_pos%%%"
if %_dot_pos% EQU 1 (
    set "varb="
) else (
    call set "varb=%%elvariato:~-%_dot_pre%%%"
)
:showResults
rem debugging output 
echo vara="%vara%" varb="%varb%"
goto :eof
```

**Sample output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SU\1302882c.bat
vara="spain is in.the.european" varb="union"

==> D:\bat\SU\1302882c.bat "."      a dot only
vara="" varb=""

==> D:\bat\SU\1302882c.bat "nodots"
vara="nodots" varb=""

==> D:\bat\SU\1302882c.bat ".leading dot only"
vara="" varb="leading dot only"

==> D:\bat\SU\1302882c.bat "trailing dot only."
vara="trailing dot only" varb=""

==> D:\bat\SU\1302882c.bat "1st.dot.2nd.dot.another.dot.more.dots"
vara="1st.dot.2nd.dot.another.dot.more" varb="dots"
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%_auxiliary:~0,1%` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%elvariato:.=%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: I looked at a lot of posts. This is the only one that handled multiple spaces and periods.

Answer (score 0):

This may be “cheating”,
but, as long as your delimiter is dot (“**`.`**”),
you can use a trick:
pretend that your string is a filename:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    ︙
for %%A in (%elvariato%) do set "vara=%%~nA" & set "varb_plus=%%~xA"
for /f "delims=. tokens=1" %%B in ("!varb_plus!") do set varb=%%B
```

`%%~nA` and `%%~xA` treat `%%A` as a pathname
and extract the base filename part and the extension, respectively. 
Base filename is defined to be everything up to the last dot,
so that’s your `vara`. 
Extension is the last dot and everything after it (e.g., “`.txt`”),
which is not what you want. 
So we assign the extension to `varb_plus` —
it’s the desired value for `varb` plus a dot. 
Then it’s easy to use `for /f "delims=. tokens=1"`
to get the part after the dot.

Because `%%~nA` is returning the *base filename part* of `%%A`,
this will fail if your full variable contains `/` or `\`. 
You might be able to handle this by looking at `%%~pA`
(the pathname part of `%%A`),
but it’s not immediately obvious how to do this —
especially if it can contain *either* `/` or `\`.

Comment: I do have some ideas on how to handle slashes in the value by testing `%%~pA`; let me know if you need them.

Comment: what's that 3 dot symbol on the second line?

Comment: @SimonS: It’s a *vertical [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis).*

Comment: Sorry I don't want to spam on your answer, but what does that do in batch? I've never seen it

Comment: You’re not meant to actually *use* that character. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) says, it *represents* an omitted part — specifically, the code that sets `elvariato`. I use it to indicate that the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` statement should be at the beginning of the file, and not immediately before the statement(s) that use `!varb_plus!`. (Although, I suppose, in this case, it might not really matter.)